# Making data available in a table all the time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, partitioning

I'm currently using the below method to have data available in a table:

1. A materialized view is fully refreshed (this process takes about 2 hours).
2. The rows from the MV are inserted into my final table (FINAL_DATA).

This way, I am able to have data available in FINAL_DATA for the time that it takes for the MV to refresh. However, the data there is unavailable for the time between I delete all the rows and insert them again into FINAL_DATA. Ideally I would like data to be always available in FINAL_DATA.
I have heard that there is a better way to achieve this using partitions. What that would be?

Comment: Is this data you need to be able to update, or is it read-only?

Comment: Read only @pmdba But now I am curious on what the difference would be in the implementation if I had to update it.

Comment: If read only, why copy the data out of the MV? Why not just use the MV? Data should be fully available at all times that way.

Comment: @pmdba because the MV takes 2 hours to refresh.

Comment: But original/previous data is available during the refresh. There should never be a time when the MV is empty, unlike your table.

Comment: @pmdba sometimes the MV fails and moves to 'invalid state'. I would like to protect myself against that scenario.

Comment: @pmdba also, we are using the atomic refresh to update the MV, because it is faster (it takes ages otherwise), and I think the data is not available all the time with this option.

Comment: Atomic refresh only means that MVs in a refresh group are updated in a single transaction, rather than individually in separate transactions. It should have no effect on a single, stand-alone MV. Data is *always* available in an MV during a refresh. A failed refresh and "invalid state" should only apply to the scheduled job, not the data itself (the failed transaction would simply roll back). If non-atomic refresh is taking a long time, try tuning your `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` initialization parameter.